# (Contest problem) Count the number of squares that are not attacked by bishops

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, chess

**My solution is in below.**

The bishop in chess is a piece that attacks all squares on the same diagonal (on both diagonals).

[image: Picture]

Shakhriyar placed m bishops on a chessboard of size n * n. Now he wants to count the number of squares that are not attacked by bishops. Help Shahriyar in this matter.

Input data
First line contains two integers: the size n (1 ≤ n ≤ 10^6) of a chessboard and the number of bishops m (1 ≤ m ≤ 10^5). Each of the next m lines contains pair of integers: r[i] и c[i] (1 ≤ r[i], c[i] ≤ n) - the numbers of row and column where the bishop number i is located. The bishops are numbered from 1 to m. All bishops are located on different squares.

Output data
Print the number of squares not attacked by the bishops.

https://www.eolymp.com/en/problems/9630

Input example #1

10 6

4 7

8 5

8 7

6 2

9 7

8 4

Output example #1

33

I solved up to here:

(sorry for the messy picture)

[image: Picture 1] [image: Picture 2]

**diagonals=2n-1**

**d-diagonals number**

**(i;j)-coordinats of points(y,x)**

From picture 1:

1:(6;1)

2:(5;1); (6;2)

3:(4;1); (5;2); (6;3)

4:(3;1); (4;2); (5;3); (6;4)

...

10:(1;5); (2;6)

11:(1;6)

**d=n-(i-j);**

From  picture 2:

1:(1;1)

2:(1;2); (2;1)

3:(1;3); (3;1); (2;2)

4:(1;4) (4;1) (2;3) (3;2)

...

**d=i+j-1;**

**Intersections of diagonals:**

| Diagonals from picture 1(2) | Diagonals from picture 2(1) |
| --- | --- |
| 1, 11 | 6 |
| 2, 10 | 5, 6, 7 |
| 3, 9 | 4,5,6,7,8 |
| 4, 8 | 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 |
| 5, 7 | 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 |
| 6 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 |

**While finding the number of points, Intersections are preventing me . How can I fix this?**

My code(C++):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    set<int> hit_diagonals1,hit_diagonals2;
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(int k=0,i,j; k<m; k++){///O(m)-->1e5
        cin>>i>>j;
        hit_diagonals1.insert(n-(i-j));
        hit_diagonals2.insert(i+j-1);
    }
    int cnt=0;//hit_points_number
    
    //.....
    
    cout<<n*n-cnt<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use two sets and not just the one?

Comment: At first I used one, but then I realized that the intersections had to be find

Comment: Be careful you will pickup a lot of bad habits when doing competitive coding (it is NOT a good way to learn C++). `using namespace std;`, `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);`, `cin.tie(0);` already show you are blindly copying things without understanding them.

Comment: How this question is different from the previous one https://stackoverflow.com/q/76397637 ?

Comment: it closed and it was not  answered, and i shall delete it

Comment: Speed is found in algorithms, not in prematurely optimizing your output. The performance gains (if any) by "optimizing" io/streams should be below the accuracy ithat competitive coding sites can even measure (they're pretty unreliable being shared by many users concurrently etc.). Optimization should always be done based on measurements: ideally profilers

Comment: If your goal is to learn C++, look at these : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date with the latest guidelines.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thanks for advice and links, I know affect of algorithm to speed , but if input is many things (especially in graphs matrix) , cin can be slow and i swap it with scanf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this in O(m log m) time using a diagonal [sweep-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) algorithm.

First, let's call the diagonals where x+y is constant the "backslash diagonals" and the "slash" diagonals will be the ones where x-y is constant.

Now we can consider the backslash diagonals in order from 0 to 2m+1 (the maximum x+y).

First, make a list of "events".  For each bishop position (x,y), record:

- (x+y, 'cover'): This indicates the backslash diagonal the the bishop completely covers;
- (abs(x-y), 'enter'):  The first backslash diagonal at which the bishop starts covering its slash diagonal:
- (m+m-1-abs(x,y), ' exit'): The first backslash diagonal at which the bishop no longer covers its slash diagonal.

Make an initially empty dictionary `slashes` to keep track of the number of bishops covering each slash diagonal.  While modifying this map, you will also make sure that you can keep track of the number of non-zero entries.

Now, sort the events by backslash diagonal, and process them in order, grouping by backslash diagonal.

For each backslash group <= (m-1)+(m-1):
- accumulate the number of unattacked squares since the last backslash group with events.  Since there were no events in these backslashes, that means that you can calculate the number of unattacked squares with a simple formula.
- process the 'enter' and 'exit' events to update the `slashes` map.
- if there is a 'cover' event, then just go to the next group, because there are no unattacked squares in the backslash.
- otherwise, use the number of non-zero entries in `slashes` to calculate the number of unattacked squares in the backslash.  It's the length of the backslash diagonal minus the number of non-zero entries.

Finally, if you didn't process backslash 2(m-1), the last one, then use the add the number of squares in all the unprocessed backslashes -- they aren't attacked.

Note that the constraints in the problems suggest that an O(m<sup>2</sup>), O(m + n), or O(m + n log n) algorithm is expected.  This is O(m log m), which is then better than they expect.

Comment: Should be 2m+2.  Along a backslash diagonal, x+y is constant, so they can be numbered by the sum.  The first one is x+y=0, the last one is x+y = m+1 + m+1.

Answer (score 1):

As the diagonals have identifying numbers that are in a small range, you can use a vector for this instead of a set. The index is the diagonal number, and the corresponding value indicates whether the diagonal is attacked or not (0 or 1).

The algorithm could first iteration the forward diagonals (/) and only when it finds that diagonal is not attacked, it could iterate the relevant crossing diagonals to count those that are also not attacked. Note that the number of crossing diagonals depends on which forward diagonal is under consideration, and the numbers of these crossing diagonals are always 2 steps apart (they are either all odd or all even for a given forward diagonal).

Here is how it could be coded:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int n, m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;

    std::vector<int> diagonals(4*n, 1); // initialise with all 1
    
    for (int bishop = 0, row, col; bishop < m; bishop++) {
        std::cin >> row >> col;
        // Mark the two diagonals that this biship covers with 0
        diagonals[row+col] = diagonals[3*n+(row-col)] = 0;
    }
    
    int freeCount = 0;
    for (int forwIdx = 2, lowIdx = 3*n, highIdx = lowIdx; forwIdx <= 2*n; forwIdx++) {
        if (diagonals[forwIdx]) { // Non-attacked diagonal (/)
            // The crossing diagonals (\) always have same parity (+2)
            for (int crossIdx = lowIdx; crossIdx <= highIdx; crossIdx += 2) {
                freeCount += diagonals[crossIdx];
            }
        }
        int grow = forwIdx <= n ? 1 : -1; 
        lowIdx -= grow;
        highIdx+= grow;
    }
    std::cout << freeCount << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```